Unable to add user shortcut
After creating my first shortcut, which worked well, I tried to make a new one to move the cursor to the end of the line, but here I faced a problem: the shortcut didn't work.
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaults
[
  {
    "key": "ctrl+n",
    "command": "explorer.newFile"
  },
  {
    "key": "shift+space",
    "command": "editor.action.insertCursorAtEndOfEachLineSelected",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
]

I checked if the key combination was already used, but it wasn't. I also tried other combinations, but the problem was still consistent.


It looks like you must have the line selected (or at least text at the end of it) for that command to work.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish, and what is selected in the line - give an example.

Yes, you are right I misunderstood the command, the one  I needed was "cursorEndSelect" and not "editor.action.insertCursorAtEndOfEachLineSelected".Thank you for answering.

I think the right command is "cursorEnd" because "cursorEndSelect" will select the text from the current position to the end of the line. However, I think you want to move the cursor to the end of the line, so you need to use the command I mentioned before.
